# Are LEGO Clikits elements compatible with the brick system?

Tags: compatibility

Are LEGO Clikits elements in some way compatible with the LEGO brick system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to ***[this](http://thebrickblogger.com/2010/12/lego-clikits/)*** review on *The Brick Blogger*, yes, *BUT*...

After watching ***[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpBYYbhEWhw)*** video by *Maniac4Bricks*, it seems the compatibility is very limited.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Also the frames are to some extent compatible.
The entire frame is 9 studs wide, the little holes align with studs.
I've seen this frame used in a GBC module.

[image: brickits]